# Is there a way in Python/Pandas to use a generic variable name with a wildcard to select all similar columns?

Tags: python, pandas

In Stata, if I typed `Week_*`, it would select all columns Week_1, Week_2, etc. Is there a similar way to do this in Python/Pandas?

Code example, including last line for what I want to do.

```
# One-hot Encode Week: Create variables Week_1, Week_2, ... etc.
dt_temp0 = dt_temp0.join(pd.get_dummies(dt_temp0['Week'],prefix='Week'))

# Features to Use
feat_cols = ['lag2_tfk_total','lag3_tfk_total','lag2_Trips_pp','lag3_Trips_pp',
             'ClinicID_fac', 'Week_*']

x_train = dt_temp1.loc[dt_temp1['train'] == 1,feat_cols]
```

Comment: [select_columns](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select.select_columns) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) offers this functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found another way to do this, as well... using `filter()`. Then you just have to concatenate the string arrays together. Thanks for all the help!

```
week_cols = dt_temp0.filter(regex = "Week_" ).columns.tolist()
feat_cols = ['ClinicID_fac','lag2_tfk_total','lag3_tfk_total','lag2_Trips_pp','lag3_Trips_pp'] + week_cols
```

Answer (score 2):

You could select your week columns with a list comprehension:

```
week_cols = [col for col in df_temp1.columns if col.startswith('Week_')]
feat_cols = ['lag2_tfk_total','lag3_tfk_total','lag2_Trips_pp','lag3_Trips_pp',
             'ClinicID_fac', *week_cols]
```

You can combine these into one line if you want.